# Post Data from vue.js to phpmailer on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, vue.js, axios

Is there any way to make a POST Request from my local `.vue` file to an local `phpmailer` file with `axios` or `fetch`

Here is my actually stand of submit script:

```
methods: {
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.preventDefault());
  axios
      .post('mail.php', querystring.stringify(this.form), {
        headers: {
          'X-Requested-Width': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      })
      .then( res => {
        res.send = true;
      })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log(err.response);
      })
  }
}
```

But if i will submit, I get this error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/mail.php 404 (Not Found)
```

But this file is on that Server and in the right folder.

Have anyone an idea how I can fix this error?

Comment: on what serveri is the phpmailer running?

Comment: the phpmailer ist running on the same server as my vue-app

Comment: does it work with cURL? because it's not looking like a vue-specific issue to me

Comment: so I tried the curl.post function and i get no error but the system does not send any mail to me.